# What's the term for a r.v. X "upper bounding" Y probabilistically?

Tags: probability, random-variable, terminology, measure-theory

What's the term for when a random variable $X$ has a higher probability of being greater than t than the probability of $Y$ being greater than $t$ for all real $t$? I recall reading a term for this somewhere but can't remember where, and this this turns out to be annoying to Google. I don't want to end up making up a new definition when one exists somewhere. Additionally, are there any other related notions of a random variable upper/lower bounding another? It doesn't really make sense to say $X > Y$ for example (unless maybe if the essential min of $X$ is strictly greater than the essential max of $Y$).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance  Concerning related concepts, see *inter alia* https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497207, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291675/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328860, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122381, and other links [from a site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stochastic+domina*).

Comment: thank you---this is it!